# Syntax error { expected

Tags: android

There are two errors as indicated on line 28 and the line, could somebody why I am getting these errors

```
package com.xcxcxc;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class UserDict extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.audiolistmain);
}

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
ListView audiolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.audioList);


String[] mProjection =
{
    UserDictionary.Words._ID,    
    UserDictionary.Words.WORD,   
    UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE  
};

String mSelectionClause = null;
String[] mSelectionArgs = {""};
static final String[] DBFIELDS= {UserDictionary.Words.WORD,     UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE};
static final int[] LISTFIELDS = { R.id.dictWord,R.id.locale};

String mSearchString = "m";  //syntax error on token ";" { expected after this token
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)) {
mSelectionClause = null;
mSelectionArgs[0] = "";

} else {
    mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " = ?";
    mSelectionArgs[0] = mSearchString;

}   

Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,  
mProjection,                       
mSelectionClause,                  
mSelectionArgs,                    
null);

if (null == mCursor) {
Log.e("Cursor returned null, query could not be performed","");
} else if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {
Toast.makeText(this, "nowords"+mSearchString+"found",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
int[] mWordListItems = { R.id.dictWord, R.id.locale};
String[] mWordListColumns =
{
UserDictionary.Words.WORD,   
UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE  
};

SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
getApplicationContext(),               
R.layout.row,                   
mCursor,                            
DBFIELDS,                      
LISTFIELDS); 


audiolist.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

}   // syntax error insert } to complete class body
```

Comment: please indent your code...then the problem will be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The line immediately following the line you're showing as flagged with the error is code which should be inside a method, but isn't. I'm going to guess that you didn't mean to close `onCreate` after this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.audiolistmain);
```

and that all the code you've listed here is supposed to be part of that method. Just remove the closing bracket `}` on the next line, and add two closing brackets at the end of the file, and it should match up.

Comment: I still don't understand why android expects me to put certain code in a separate method, Could somebody explain, I have read and read java code but could not find when a certain code can't be put in main class but has to be in a separate method please please? I am almost going mad on this thing and can't find an answer

Comment: Put simply, all code must be inside a method. You can define (and in Java, initialise) variables inside a class definition (UserDict in this case), but all other code must be inside a method. So, for example, `int x = 0` can be outside a method because all it does is create and set the initial value of a variable. However, `while(x < 10) { x = x + 1; }` *must* be inside a method, because it isn't initialising a variable, it's performing logic. If your call looks roughly like `VarType variable_name = initial_value`, it should be ok to put outside a method. Otherwise, it must be inside.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the second issue you need a closing "}" at the end of the file to finish off the class body.

Answer (score 0):

If you still don't get what @Xono said

remove the { of this

```
    package com.xcxcxc;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.provider.UserDictionary;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class UserDict extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audiolistmain);
    }   <--------------- THIS ONE
    ^
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
 THIS ONE
```

And place it at the very bottom....

**EDIT:**

also add another { to close the class.

Comment: And add an extra `}` at the bottom - the UserDict class definition isn't closed either, as @Cobra_Mo pointed out

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.xcxcxc;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class UserDict extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audiolistmain);
    // "{" ====>> Removed

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ListView audiolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.audioList);


    String[] mProjection =
    {
        UserDictionary.Words._ID,    
        UserDictionary.Words.WORD,   
        UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE  
    };

    String mSelectionClause = null;
    String[] mSelectionArgs = {""};
    static final String[] DBFIELDS= {UserDictionary.Words.WORD,     UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE};
    static final int[] LISTFIELDS = { R.id.dictWord,R.id.locale};

    String mSearchString = "m";  //syntax error on token ";" { expected after this token
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)) {
        mSelectionClause = null;
        mSelectionArgs[0] = "";

    } else {
        mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " = ?";
        mSelectionArgs[0] = mSearchString;
    }   

    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query( UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,  
                mProjection,                       
                mSelectionClause,                  
                mSelectionArgs,                    
                null);

    if (null == mCursor) {
        Log.e("Cursor returned null, query could not be performed","");
    } else if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "nowords"+mSearchString+"found",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        int[] mWordListItems = { R.id.dictWord, R.id.locale};
        String[] mWordListColumns =
        {
            UserDictionary.Words.WORD,   
            UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE  
        };

        SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                        getApplicationContext(),               
                                        R.layout.row,                   
                                        mCursor,                            
                                        DBFIELDS,                      
                                        LISTFIELDS); 


        audiolist.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    } 
}   //===========> "}" added
}   //===========> "}" added
```